# Spring Application - Getting images on Amazon S3 to client

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am building a Spring Web Application hosted on Elastic Beanstalk. I use S3 to store user uploaded images which works great. What I don't understand is how fetching images from S3 to the client work. I found three alternatives.

1.Get the image in a controller and send it to the client. Like this:

```
S3Object object = amazonS3Client.getObject("bucketname", "path/to/image");
```

2.Open up all images and reach it directly by an URL in the client. Something like this:

```
 <img src="http://aws.amazon.com/bucket/path/to/image.jpg">
```

3.Use signed download URLs that only working for a certain time. Like this:

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest("bucketname", "path/to/image");
String url = conn.generatePresignedUrl(request)
```

Im not sure which approach to go for. Routing it through the web server seems unnecessary, since it loads the server. Open the URLs to anyone might higher requests and costs since anyone can use the images. And the third way is new to me, haven't really seen anyone practising this which makes me insecure if this is really the way to go.

So, how is this usually done?

And how is this used in the development environment versus production environment. I guess its not changing? Or is it common to use spring profiles to change the location of static content while developing and only use S3 for production?

If your hosting Javascript, CSS on S3, is it then most common to go for approach 2 and open them up for everyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me it depends upon the requirements you have for access control for images uploaded by a user.

If the images are non-sensitive i.e. it wouldn't really matter if someone else got hold of another user's images, then I would go for approach 2.

If on the other hand it would be a disaster if someone managed to get hold of another user's images, then I would go for approach 3 (or some other form of expiring token access to the images).

The last time I did this I went for approach 2 because the images were non-sensitive. To try and prevent people from discovering images, we did apply a hashing function to the name of the image, but again I wasn't massively concerned about this. In either case, a well defined bucket structure that can be easily worked out by the application when constructing the URL for an image is useful. So for you, perhaps consider something like:

- s3:bucket_name/images/users/<hashed_and_salted_user_name>/<user_images>

As for you request regarding dev vs prod environments, then matching a bucket name to the Spring profile is the approach we used. So for example:

1. s3:bucket_name/prod/images/users/user/foo.jpg
2. s3:bucket_name/dev/images/users/user/foo.jpg

As you can probably guess we had Spring profiles named "prod" and "dev". The code for building image URLs took into account the name of the current Spring profile when creating the URL. Gives a nice separation between environments.

In terms of CSS and Javascript, then I tend to host obfuscated/minified versions in the production S3 buckets, and full versions in the dev/test buckets (mainly for performance rather that trying to hide code). In addition I'd use some sort versioning/naming structure in how you host CSS/Javascript in S3 so that you can determine what "version" of resources your app is using. So for example:

- s3:bucket_name/css/app-1.css
- s3:bucket_name/css/app-2.css

The version of the CSS/Javascript resources is updated each time you push a new version into production.

By going down this path you kinda look at S3 as the final resting place for a piece of Javascript/CSS when it is ready to go into the wide world of production. Once there, you know it will never change. If CSS/Javascript does change, then the user has to fetch a new resource from S3 as the version will be incremented. You can hook this into your build process so that your main app is always referencing the latest version of CSS/Javascript.  I found this has two useful functions:

1. Makes it very easy to determine which version of a resource your application is running with
2. Makes it very easy to cache resources (either with browser or something like CloudFront) as you know they will never change

Hope that helps.

Comment: Great answer thank you! I will go for approach 2 since its non sensitive images (its avatars). Do you save each image url to the database? Since I don't know the image extension I thinking of saving that to each users entity in the database. My URLs looks like this:
s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/images/avatars/USERID-avatar.EXTENSION

Comment: Generally I'd avoid saving the URL if at all possible because you'll run into the inevitable scenario that the URL will change and you then have to update the DB. Far better to be able to generate the URL given a particular user. In terms of image extension I'd go for two options, 1: Force the user to only upload a specific extension, or if that is not feasible, 2: store the profile image extension in the db against the user (as you suggested).